# I'm having trouble with content based recommendation system prediction (NOT TDIDF)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recommendation-engine, content-based-retrieval

I keep getting the following error --> Exception: Dim. mismatch: Test data contains 3 items, while Content contains 1526 items. Please make sure the columns of test and content match.

Can someone help me? I've been working on this code for a few days. My entire body of code is below.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from IESEGRecSys.Functions import *
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from surprise import KNNBasic
from surprise import Dataset, Reader

user_artists = pd.read_table("user_artists.dat")


user_artists['ratings'] = 0
user_artists.loc[user_artists['weight'] <= user_artists['weight'].quantile(1), 'ratings'] = 5
user_artists.loc[user_artists['weight'] < user_artists['weight'].quantile(0.8), 'ratings'] = 4
user_artists.loc[user_artists['weight'] < user_artists['weight'].quantile(0.6), 'ratings'] = 3
user_artists.loc[user_artists['weight'] < user_artists['weight'].quantile(0.4), 'ratings'] = 2
user_artists.loc[user_artists['weight'] < user_artists['weight'].quantile(0.2), 'ratings'] = 1

data = user_artists[['userID','artistID','ratings']]

data.head()
data.shape

# train-test split
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# reset index
train = train.reset_index(drop=True)
test = test.reset_index(drop=True)

print(data.shape)
print(train.shape)
print(test.shape)

tags = pd.read_table("tags.dat",  encoding = 'unicode_escape')
user_taggedartists = pd.read_table("user_taggedartists.dat")

user_tag_merged = pd.merge(user_taggedartists, tags, on="tagID", how="inner")
user_tag_merged_updated = pd.merge(user_tag_merged, data, on=(["userID","artistID"]),how="inner")

movie=user_tag_merged_updated
movie

data2 = data[['userID','artistID','ratings']]

# train-test split
train, test2 = train_test_split(data2, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# reset index
train = train.reset_index(drop=True)
test = test.reset_index(drop=True)

print(data2.shape)
print(train.shape)
print(test.shape)

data_pivot2 = data2.pivot_table(index='artistID', values='ratings', columns='userID').fillna(0)
data_pivot2.head()

movie2 = [['tagID','artistID','year']]

movie2 = user_tag_merged_updated.pivot_table(index='tagID', values='year', columns='userID').fillna(0)

movie2.head()

# Content based as a function

from numpy.linalg import norm

def simil_cosine(a,b):
    return np.dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))


def ContentBased(content_data, test_data, NN):

    cdata = content_data.reset_index(drop=True).copy()

    # store user and item dimensions
    dim = cdata.shape[0]
    nr_user = cdata.shape[0]

    if test_data.shape[1] != dim:
        raise Exception('Dim. mismatch: Test data contains {} items, while Content contains {} items. Please make sure the columns of test and content match.'\
            .format(test_data.shape[1], dim))

    # similarity matrices
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(dim, dim), dtype=np.float)
    matrixNN = np.zeros(shape=(dim, dim), dtype=np.float)

    # compute similarity
    for i, row in cdata.iterrows():
        for j, col in cdata.iterrows():
            if i <= j: continue
            else: matrix[i][j] = simil_cosine(np.array(row),np.array(col))

    # copy values to other diagonal
    matrix = matrix + matrix.T - np.diag(np.diag(matrix))

    print('Similarity calculation done...')

    # mask all values that are not nearest neighbors
    cutoff = lambda x,cv: x if x >= cv else 0.0
    v_cutoff = np.vectorize(cutoff)

    for i in range(dim):
        crit_val = -np.sort(-matrix[i])[NN-1]
        matrixNN[i] = v_cutoff(matrix[i], crit_val)

    print('Nearest neighbor selection done...')

    # predict user-item ratings in test_data
    prediction = np.zeros(shape=(nr_user, dim), dtype=np.float)

    for i in range(nr_user):
        num = np.matmul(np.array(test_data.iloc[i,:]), matrixNN)
        denom = matrixNN.sum(axis=0) # column sums
        prediction[i] = num/denom

    print('Prediction done...')

    # return DataFrame
    return pd.DataFrame(prediction, index=test_data.index, columns=test_data.columns)

cb_pred = ContentBased(movie2,data_pivot2, 10)

# Content Based as a Class

from numpy.linalg import norm

class ContentBased:

    def simil_cosine(self, a,b):
        return np.dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))

    def __init__(self, NN):
        self.NN = NN
        
    
    def fit(self, content_data):
        cdata = content_data.reset_index(drop=True).copy()
        self.item_dim = cdata.shape[0]
        self.matrix   = np.zeros(shape=(self.item_dim, self.item_dim), dtype=np.float)
        self.matrixNN = np.zeros(shape=(self.item_dim, self.item_dim), dtype=np.float)

        # compute similarity
        for i, row in cdata.iterrows():
            for j, col in cdata.iterrows():
                if i <= j: continue
                else: self.matrix[i][j] = self.simil_cosine(np.array(row),np.array(col))

        # copy values to other diagonal
        self.matrix = self.matrix + self.matrix.T - np.diag(np.diag(self.matrix))

        cutoff = lambda x,cv: x if x >= cv else 0.0
        v_cutoff = np.vectorize(cutoff)

        for i in range(self.item_dim):
            crit_val = -np.sort(-self.matrix[i])[self.NN-1]
            self.matrixNN[i] = v_cutoff(self.matrix[i], crit_val)

    
    def predict(self, test_data):

        if test_data.shape[1] != self.item_dim:
            raise Exception('Dim. mismatch: Test data contains {} items, while Content contains {} items. Please make sure the columns of test and content match.'\
                .format(test_data.shape[1], self.item_dim))
```

I keep getting the following error --> Exception: Dim. mismatch: Test data contains 3 items, while Content contains 1526 items. Please make sure the columns of test and content match.